# String -> ByteString and reverse

Tags: haskell, bytestring

In my Haskell Program I need to work with Strings and ByteStrings:

```
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS  (ByteString)
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as C8 (pack)
import Data.Char                   (chr)

stringToBS :: String -> ByteString
stringToBS str = C8.pack str

bsToString :: BS.ByteString -> String
bsToString bs = map (chr . fromEnum) . BS.unpack $ bs
```

`bsToString` works fine, but `stringToBS` results with following error at compiling:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘ByteString’
                with actual type ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
    NB: ‘ByteString’ is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal’
        ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
          is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Internal’
    In the expression: pack str
    In an equation for ‘stringToBS’: stringToBS str = pack str
```

But I need to let it be `ByteString` from `Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS  (ByteString)` for further working functions in my code.

Any idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: BTW, I hope you know what you are doing. A `ByteString` is a sequence of bytes, and not a string: conversion between them fundamentally depends on a given encoding. In particular, `Char8` assumes that everything is encoded using latin-1, and silently truncates everything else.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using `String` and not `Text` the conversion with encoding/decoding is a bit more straightforward.

Comment: Because my other functions requires String

Answer (score 4):

You are working with both strict ByteStrings and lazy ByteStrings which are two different types.

This import:

```
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS  (ByteString)
```

makes `ByteString` refer the lazy ByteStrings, so the type signature of your `stringToBS` doesn't match it's definition:

```
stringToBS :: String -> ByteString  -- refers to lazy ByteStrings
stringToBS str = C8.pack str        -- refers to strict ByteStrings
```

I think it would be a better idea to use `import qualified` like this:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
```

and use `BS.ByteString` and `LBS.ByteString` to refer to strict / lazy ByteStrings.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert between lazy and non-lazy versions using `fromStrict`, and `toStrict` (both functions are in the lazy bytestring module).

Comment: `urlDecode True (stringToBS str)` with `stringToBS str = BS.fromStrict $ C8.pack str` brings me: `Couldn't match expected type ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
                with actual type ‘ByteString’` how to solve?